# How I can handling the setOutputFile from MediaRecorder to take Uri android 10

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-mediarecorder, scoped-storage

I need to record voice this function setOutputFile() takes a path of the output file and need to handling scoped storage that I have Uri not path what should I do?

```
public void startRecording() {
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recordingName = getFilename();
    recorder.setOutputFile(recordingName);
    recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
    recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
        handler.post(updateVisualizer);
    } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this line should be changed

```
 recordingName = getFilename();
 recorder.setOutputFile(recordingName);
```

Comment: You can try [this version of `setOutputFile()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/MediaRecorder?hl=en#setoutputfile). Or, record to some file that you control (e.g., in `getFilesDir()`) and copy it to the location pointed to by the `Uri` when recording is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I used the public folder for my app
like this example
https://github.com/CWMChapman/Audio_Memos

```
public void startRecording(Button b) {
        // state = mounted or unmounted
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        Log.d(TAG, state);

        Context ctx = this.getApplicationContext();
        File audioDir = new File(ctx.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "AudioMemos");
        audioDir.mkdirs();
        String audioDirPath = audioDir.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.d(TAG, "Recording file location: " + audioDirPath);

        Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); // current time
        String curTimeStr = currentTime.toString().replace(" ", "_");

        File recordingFile = new File(audioDirPath + "/" + curTimeStr + ".m4a");
        Log.d(TAG, "Created file: " + recordingFile.getName());

//        try {
//        } catch (IOException e) {
//            Log.e(TAG, "external storage access error");
//            return;
//        }

        mr = new MediaRecorder();
        mr.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mr.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mr.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        mr.setOutputFile(recordingFile.getAbsolutePath());

        try {
            mr.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }
        mr.start();
    }
```